# function rightshift($num, $bits) is not working in server

Tags: php

```
function rightshift($num, $bits) { 
return bcdiv($num, bcpow('2', $bits)); 
} 
echo rightshift(1024,8));
```

In php its working in local system but it is not working in server.

Comment: php has native rightshift operators, so why did you write your own?

Comment: oh, right, arbitrary precision. OK.

Comment: Please quantify "not working". Are any errors thrown?

Comment: @middaparka I think the most likely reason is that BC Math isn't installed on their server. They should have explained better, but I can't see any other reason for this to fail.

Comment: @Dave I totally agree, but this is an exceptionally lazy question, so I thought it might be nice if the OP actually checked the error logs to discover the inevitable "Fatal error: Call to undefined function bcdiv()".

Comment: @middaparka yeah, I'd have to agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your local system is Windows, but the server is Linux?

The Windows build of PHP has built-in support, while the Linux builds need to be compiled with an option. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php. This doesn't seem to be widely enabled by default.

How to enable it will depend on your hosting provider. If you have full access to the server, recompile PHP with that flag set and you'll be fine. Here's a page which is targeted at DreamHost, but the guides should roughly apply to any server environment where you're allowed to install your own PHP: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/BCMath